# The button is not working after hiding

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a button that when user click on it, a list appears in the screen.

i added this event for opening the list:

```
$(".js-language-trigger").on('click',this.openOptions.bind(this));

openOptions(){
$(document.body).find(".nav-link-language").show("slow");
}
```

and this event for closing the list

```
$(".nav-link-language-holder").on('click','img', 'a', this.selectLanguage.bind(this));


selectLanguage(e){
 $(document.body).find(".nav-link-language-holder").slideUp("slow");
}
```

The problem is when the list will be hidden again (after opening), when i click on the button to open it again, it wont open and not working at all.
Can any one help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: You're using a different selector. Try changing $(document.body).find(".nav-link-language-holder").slideUp("slow"); to $(document.body).find(".nav-link-language").slideUp("slow");

Comment: @VictorStoddard thank you for your help. I replaced slideUp with hide, but the problem is still there. Actually i dont understand what you mean by trying using absolute positioning for the object

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `slideUp()` but it might not work on objects that don't have absolute positioning or aren't block level. But I think your problem is likely that you are looking for `.nav-link-language` in one reference and `.nav-link-language-holder` in the other. They likely should match.

Comment: @VictorStoddard thank you so much, it works  i cant thank you enough